# multiple gmap marker side by side instead of on top (when same location)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I place some marker (own icons) on a google map using jgmap3 (jquery). Basicly this works fine but I have the problem when there are more then one marker for one zip code. The first marker isn't visible because of marker 2 which is on top.
Is there a way to place them side by side?

Comment: Sounds like you want something like [this](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/weve-had-two-different-google-maps-api.html) (scroll down to the map photo). See [OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier) for the library.

Comment: how about change zoom levels